# supervisor - how to run multiple commands

Tags: python, celery, supervisord

I'm managing a Celery worker that processes queue via Supervisor.

Here's my /etc/supervisor/celery.conf:

```
[program:celery]
command = /var/worker/venv/bin/celery worker -A a_report_tasks -Q a_report_process --loglevel=INFO
directory=/var/worker
user=nobody
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 60
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
killasgroup=true
priority=998
```

How do I add this second command to run?

```
/var/worker/venv/bin/celery worker -A b_report_tasks -Q b_report_process --loglevel=INFO
```

I tried separating the two commands on the same line with `&&` (resulted in a syntax error), adding an entirely separate `[program:celery]` section to this same file (resulted in only the first one being run), and creating an entirely different `celery1.conf` file in the same directory (resulted in only the original/first one being run).

Comment: From your posting, the first command is the same as the second one. Is that a typo?

Comment: Oops! Yes, that was a typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add a second section with a *different task name*. If two tasks have the same task name, the latter overwrites the former.

```
[program:celeryb]
command = /var/worker/venv/bin/celery worker -A b_report_tasks -Q b_report_process --loglevel=INFO
directory=/var/worker
user=nobody
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 60
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
killasgroup=true
priority=998
```

You can also group them so both tasks get restarted as a group:

```
[group:celery-workers]
programs=celery,celeryb
priority=999
```