# How to activate python virtual environment in supervisor?

Tags: python, virtualenv, supervisord

**What I want to do?**

Activate tensorflow_p36 environment and run `python wsgi.py`

**What my `supervisord.conf` file looks like?**

```
[program:my_program]
command = /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin/python /home/ec2-user/abc/wsgi.py
directory= /home/ec2-user/abc/
environment=PATH= "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin"
user= ec2-user
redirect_stderr = True
stdout_logfile = /home/ec2-user/abc/logs/gunicorn/gunicorn_stdout.log
stderr_logfile = /home/ec2-user/abc/logs/gunicorn/gunicorn_stderr.log
```

The file is located in default /etc/supervisord.conf location.

**What have I tried so far?**

I tried all the solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202760/how-to-use-virtualenvwrapper-in-supervisor), but the modules installed in that virtual environment are not getting imported. For example, I get errors in importing tensorflow, flask etc. Whereas, when I do the same command in terminal after `source activate tensorflow_p36` it works just fine.

I also tried grouping multiple programs suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28994845/2679662), where I activated virtual environment in first program and ran python command in second program and grouped them together. Didn't work, was still getting the same import errors.

**Extra info:**

When I run `sudo service supervisord restart`, I get following message:

Stopping supervisord:                                      [  OK  ]

Starting supervisord: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.3.4-py2.7.egg/supervisor/options.py:461: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
                                                           [  OK  ]

Answer (score 3):

Your command doesn't activate the environment - it just calls to the python in that folder. 
I'll explain the difference:

When creating an environment a python.exe file is created inside it. calling that python file will run the script with that python - but under the normal environment.

Activating the environment on the other hand, changes the PATH system variable to point out to all the packages in that environment.

in conclusion - activating the environment instead of just running the script with the python from that environment should solve your problem.

edit:
Try something like this:

```
[program:my_program]
command = source activate tensorflow_p36 && python /home/ec2-user/abc/wsgi.py
directory= /home/ec2-user/abc/
environment=PATH= "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin"
user= ec2-user
redirect_stderr = True
stdout_logfile = /home/ec2-user/abc/logs/gunicorn/gunicorn_stdout.log
stderr_logfile = /home/ec2-user/abc/logs/gunicorn/gunicorn_stderr.log
```

Comment: Yes, I understand the difference, I have tried this command: `source activate tensorflow_p36 && python /home/ec2-user/abc/wsgi.py` , but it does not seem to work. I tried using groups (as mentioned in question), but it doesn't work either. Can you share the code for what you are suggesting?

Comment: Tried it once again and it is not working. Can you try it yourself with a very simple python file? It seems like the second operation (after &&) never gets executed.

Comment: *calling that python file will run the script with that python - but under the normal environment* No, that's not true. Calling python from a virtual env automagically activates that environment. This functionality is built into Python — when `python` binary detects it's not a system or a standalone binary but a virtual env binary it activates that virtual env.

Comment: @phd I just made some tests to see, and I was wrong, but while running the python in that environment does modify the PATH it does NOT do the same thing as activating the environment. I tested this by checking the PATH variable outside any environment, then in the virtual env and then from python (using os.environ['PATH']). The result was different in each one of these. I know for a fact that activating the env instead of just calling the python solved us some module import issues in the company.

Comment: Virtual environments is not about changing `$PATH` — it is about having a separate set of python libraries, i.e. it's about changing `sys.path`.

Comment: the command doesn't know what `source` is because that's a shell command and not a program.  try this: `command = bash -c "source activate tensorflow_p36 && python /home/ec2-user/abc/wsgi.py"`